# How do I get a <div> on a nearby node in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some JavaScript that could be used throughout my app, and allow a checkbox to show/hide a nearby element.

If I have these elements:

```
<div class="optionable" style="display: block;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input checked="checked" class="form-control" 
                data-val="true" id="IsActive" 
                name="IsActive" 
                onclick="CheckboxOptionsToggle(this);" 
                type="checkbox" value="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            Chapter
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row options">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Some data here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this script:

```
CheckboxOptionsToggle = function (thisCheckbox) {
    debugger;
    var optionElement = $('.options');
    if (thisCheckbox.checked) {
        $(thisCheckbox).closest(optionElement).show();
    } else {
        $(thisCheckbox).closest(optionElement).hide();
    }
}
```

But this isn't working. I would like the checkbox with the `onclick="CheckboxOptionsToggle(this);"` to trigger the `options` element in the same `optionable` div to either show or hide.

What am I doing wrong in my JavaScript/jQuery?

**UPDATE:** This is my final solution:

```
$('.optionToggle').on('change', function () { 
    $(this).closest('.optionable').find('.options').toggle(this.checked);
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    var toggleElements = document.body.getElementsByClassName('optionToggle');
    for (var i = 0; i < toggleElements.length; i++) {
        var thisCheck = $(toggleElements[i]);
        thisCheck.closest('.optionable').find('.options').toggle(thisCheck.prop('checked'));
    }
});

<div class="optionable" style="display: block;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input checked="checked" class="form-control optionToggle" 
                data-val="true" id="IsActive" 
                name="IsActive" 
                type="checkbox" value="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            Chapter
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row options">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Some data here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be more generic, and stop using inline event handlers

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() { // or use class to not attach to all

    $(this).closest('.optionable').find('.options').toggle(this.checked);

}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/x2jqgfht/1/)

Comment: I like and selected this, because if there were more than one `optionable` it still works. Thanks.

Comment: Follow up question, what's a good way to have items toggled to match their checkbox on page load? I tried adding a similar JavaScript function like this: `$('.optionToggle').on('onload', function () { ...` but it is not getting triggered.

Comment: Just tack on `.trigger('change')` at the end, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it like

```
CheckboxOptionsToggle = function (thisCheckbox) {
    debugger;
    var optionElement = $('.options');
    if (thisCheckbox.checked) {
        $(thisCheckbox)..closest('div.optionable').find(optionElement).show();
    } else {
        $(thisCheckbox)..closest('div.optionable').find(optionElement).hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from .closes, because it is so specific, instead I would go with more reusable code like so:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggler" data-target-class="some-div" class="toggler" value="myValue" checked> Toggle Me
<div class="some-div">
  Some Text within the div.
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#toggler').on('click', function() {
    var targetClass = $(this).data('target-class');
  $('.' + targetClass).toggle($(this).checked);
});
```

JSFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/ro17nvbL/

I am using data element on the checkbox to specifiy which divs to show or hide. This allows me to not only hide/show divs but anything n the page, and not only one instance but as many as needed. Way more flexible - still does the same job.